# Travis ci in docker failing

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, yaml, docker-compose, travis-ci

**Travis Ci .yml file**

```
sudo: true

language: cpp

compiler:
  - g++

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker run -it ubuntu bash
  - apt-get install graphicsmagick

install:

  - apt-get install qt5-default
  - exit


script: "bash -c ./build.sh"
```

build.sh is just a simple make file.

Can someone explain the difference between running.

docker run -it ubuntu bash

docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

executes the first binary called bash in the container's `$PATH` 
    docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
executes the bash binary in the `/bin/` directory specifically.
For the ubuntu container both forms are very likely functionally equivalent.

To answer what I think could be your actual problem:
You're not using docker as is intended. Your script section does not execute in the container for example. You need to run all the commands, probably as a script, with a `docker run` without the interactive flag.

Comment: Tried giving the container a name and using docker exec instead. Still having issues though.